# Unable to upload a file with Crow C++ due to segmentation fault error

Tags: javascript, html, c++, web, crow

I'm currently working on a C++ web server using Crow framework. I would like to be able to send a file from a form to my server. The problem that I'm facing is a segmentation fault (core dump) when I submit the form. It seems this is the line causing the problem :
`crow::multipart::message msg(req);`

I don't know why since the request object (req) is not null. It cannot be because I'm testing the content-type before running the previous line. **Help please**.
Here is the code of my HTML page.

```
<form class="p-5" name="submitform" id="submitform">
    <div class="form-group mb-3 row">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name of the task</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3 row">
        <label for="executable" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Executable file</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="executable" name="executable">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3 row">
        <label for="data" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Data file</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="data" name="data">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    // Get the form element by its id
    var form = document.getElementById("submitform");
    // Add an event listener for the submit event
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        // Prevent the default action of the form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        // Create a new FormData object to store the form data
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        // Create a new XMLHttpRequest object to send the request to the server
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Open the request with the POST method and the /client-mode/tasks/new URL
        xhr.open("POST", "/client-mode/tasks/new");
        // Set the request header for the content type as multipart/form-data
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        // Add an event listener for the load event, which occurs when the response is received from the server
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
            // Check if the status code is 200 OK
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // Display a success alert message with the response text
                alert("Success: " + xhr.responseText);
                // Reload the window object to refresh the page
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                // Display an error alert message with the status code and response text
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        // Send the request with the form data
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
</script>
```

C++ code

```
// This route is used to create a new task from form data
CROW_ROUTE(app, "/client-mode/tasks/new").methods("POST"_method)([](crow::request req, crow::response& res) {
    // Get the content type from the request header
    std::string content_type = req.get_header_value("Content-Type");
    // Check if the content type is multipart/form-data
    if (content_type.find("multipart/form-data") != std::string::npos) {
        try {
            // Parse the request body using the crow::multipart::message class
            crow::multipart::message msg(req);
            std::cout << "Ok3" << std::endl;
            // Loop through the parts of the message
            for (const auto& part : msg.parts) {
                std::cout << "Part" << std::endl;
                std::string task_name = crow::multipart::get_header_object(part.headers, "name").value;
                std::cout << task_name << std::endl;
                // Check if the part has a filename, which means it is a file
                if (!crow::multipart::get_header_object(part.headers, "filename").value.empty()) {
                    std::cout << crow::multipart::get_header_object(part.headers, "filename").value << std::endl;
                    // Get the file name, data, and size
                    std::string file_name = crow::multipart::get_header_object(part.headers, "filename").value;
                    const char* file_data = part.body.c_str();
                    size_t file_size = part.body.size();
                    // Saving file to files folder
                    try {
                        std::ofstream out(get_files_folder() + "files/" + file_name, std::ios::binary);
                        out.write(file_data, file_size);
                        out.close();
                    } catch (const std::ios_base::failure& e) {
                        // Catch any file operation failures and print the error message
                        std::cout << "File operation failed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                    }
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Empty part" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            // Return a response to the client with a success message and a status code of 200 OK
            res.code = 201;
            res.write("File uploaded successfully"); // Change here
            res.end();
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {
            // Catch any general exceptions and print the error message
            std::cout << "Exception occurred: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            // Return a response to the client with an error message and a status code of 500 Internal Server Error
            res.code = 500;
            res.write("Internal server error"); // Change here
            res.end();
        }
    } else {
        // Return a response to the client with an error message and a status code of 400 Bad Request
        res.code = 400;
        res.write("Invalid content type"); // Change here
        res.end();
    }
});
```

I am using Crow v1.0+5.

I've tried to check if the req object was a null object, since it is a core dump to see if that is the cause of the problem. It is actually not one because the Content-Type is available.

Comment: You say `It cannot be because`... however why not verify it by dumping the value out to an external file before the suspected crash point happens?

Comment: Actually, I searched for how to write the content of req object into a text file for example. It was unsuccessful because the method used requires to create a multipart message and it leads me to a core dump. I still think the req object is not null because I can read the content-type value from it.

Comment: Is there a "stack trace" of some kind? Even without a debugger or how to use one, you *can* write whatever you want to a text file (it need not be the whole object) to narrow down where the error occurs. That is, open/append to/close the text file. And again, and again, getting progressively closer to where you think the problem is.

Comment: Your first write to the text file might be Hello. Your 2nd write World. Your 3rd write something else, and so on. After the crash occurs, examine the text file. If you only see Hello, then you know the crash occurs after it and before World. In this way you can narrow it down.

Comment: Instead of using a file, I was using cout to display a text message in the terminal and that is what helped me to find out the line causing trouble. I just removed some but there was cout << ok1; before the getting the content-type; and cout<< ok2; before parsing the req.body to a message class. Ok1 and Ok2 were displayed but Ok3 that is to be displayed after the req.body is parsed is not displayed. I have a core dump instead.

Comment: Ok. Well this is just me debugging what you should have mentioned up front with the `ok#`s. With that out the way, on its face doesnt this just look wrong `crow::multipart::message msg(req);`? What purpose is the space serving. Are you *casting* an object type onto some method `msg()`. Whats the deal here?

Answer (score 0):

In continuation from comments, that space between `crow::multipart::message` and `msg(req)` on its face looks odd.

Replace this line:

```
crow::multipart::message msg(req);
```

With this line:

```
crow::multipart::message::message(req);
```

There doesn't appear to be any method called `msg()` but one called `message()` which does indeed mutate in place.

Documentation:

https://crowcpp.org/master/reference/structcrow_1_1multipart_1_1message.html

Hope this helps. I cant claim it will solve all your problems but hopefully gets things moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for this proposition. It does not work because there is a syntax error. From the doc, I saw that message is a class so when I'm doing msq(req), I'm instantiating the message class and I am giving the request and parameter to the constructor. Now, I'll try to use the other constructor definition that takes 3 parameters as input to see if it solves the problem.